# Application.Documents.Add return null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, com

I try to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to export a word by a word template.
Some related code below:

```
    //strTemppath is a path for my word template(.doc).
    object oTemplate = strTemppath;
    var WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

This works well locally. However, after I move my application to the server the "WordDoc" object always return null. How could this happen? Is there anything to do with the configuration of the server? such as "permission" or "Com components" or anything else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the template exist at this path `strTemppath` on the server?

Comment: File.Exists(strTemppath) method return true

Comment: Silly question,but is Word installed on the server?